# Use npm protractor webdriver-manager to start selenium server at a different port

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to run E2E tests for an angular application using protractor.  I use the command `./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager` to start my selenium server.  However the default selenium server location is localhost:4444/wd/hub, but localhost:4444 is already used on my machine and this is difficult to change.  How do I start a selenium server at a port other than 4444?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use below command :

```
webdriver-manager start --seleniumPort XXXX
```